# Unable to get apex:param assignTo value to controller

Tags: apex

I have this below code for full calendar . I am unable to pass apex:param assignTo value to controller.

```
public class CalendarController {
    public list<CalendarEvent> events {get;set;}
    //public String dtFormat = 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z';
    public String eventIdTemp{get;set;}  //Selected event Id coming from vf page
    public String st{get;set;}  //Selected event start date
    public String ed{get;set;} //Selected event end date
    public List<PositionReservation__c> eventList = new List<PositionReservation__c>();
    public Boolean includeMyEvents {get;set;}
//Getting event records in constructor    
    public CalendarController() {
        eventList = [select Id, Name, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c    from PositionReservation__c];   
    }
    public PageReference pageLoad() {
        events = new list<CalendarEvent>();

        for(PositionReservation__c e : eventList) {        
            Date startDt = e.Start_Date__c;
            Date endDt = e.End_Date__c    ;
            calendarEvent newEvent = new calendarEvent();  
            newEvent.eventId = e.Id; 
            newEvent.eventTitle = 'test';
            newEvent.allDay = false;
            newEvent.eventStart = startDt.format();
           // newEvent.eventEnd = endDt.format(dtFormat);
            newEvent.url = '/' + e.Id; 
            newEvent.className = 'event-personal';
            events.add(newEvent);
        }
        return null;
    }
  // Parsing in date format and setting values  
    public void setEvent() {
    system.debug('@@@@@Entered' + ed);

        List <String>  stringParts = ed.split('T');
        List <String>  dateParts = stringParts[0].split('-');
        List <String> timeParts = stringParts[1].split(':');  

        Date dt2 = date.newinstance(Integer.valueOf(dateParts[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateParts[2]));
        for(PositionReservation__c e : eventList) {  
            if(e.Id == eventIdTemp) { 
               // e.End_Date__c= dt1;
                e.Start_Date__c= dt2;
                update e;
            }
        }
    }

  public class CalendarEvent {
    public String eventId {get;set;}
    public String eventTitle {get;set;}
    //public String eventEnd {get;set;}
    public String eventStart {get;set;}
    public String eventColor {get;set;}
    public String url {get;set;}
    public Boolean allDay {get;set;}
    public String className {get;set;}

    }  

}
```

vf page -

```
<apex:page id="pg" controller="CalendarController" action="{!pageLoad}">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
    <script src=" //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


       <style>
        #cal-options {float:left;}
        #cal-legend { float:right;}
        #cal-legend ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
        #cal-legend ul li {margin:0;padding:5px;float:left;}
        #cal-legend ul li span {display:block; height:16px; width:16px; margin-right:4px; float:left; border-radius:4px;}
        #calendar {margin-top:20px;}
        #calendar a:hover {color:#fff !important;}

        .fc-event-inner {padding:3px;}

        .fc-event {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid  #56458c;
    background:#56458c;
    font-weight: 400;

        .event-campaign {background:#56458c;border-color:#56458c;}
        .event-personal {background:#56458c;border-color:#56458c;}
         .event-birthday {background: #56458c;border-color: #56458c;}
    </style>



    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        var st = null; 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            events:
            [
                <apex:repeat value="{!events}" var="e">
                {
                id:"{!e.eventId}",

                title: "{!e.eventId}",
                start: '{!e.eventStart}',

                url: '{!e.url}',
                allDay: {!e.allDay}
                },
                </apex:repeat>
            ],

            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                    revertFunc();
                }
                //setEvnt(Indonesian Cyber Freedom :: ~.\,event.start.format(),event.end.format()); 
                //setEvnt(event.id, event.start, event.end); 

                setEvnt(event.id, event.start); 
            },

             eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {
                    var dt = new Date();
                    if (event.start < dt && event.end > dt) {
                        //element.css('background-color', '#00CDCD');
                    } else if (event.start < dt && event.end < dt) {
                       // element.css('background-color', '#77DD77');
                    } else if (event.start > dt && event.end > dt) {
                       // element.css('background-color', '#86C67C');
                    }
                }                       
        });

    });

    </script>
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Event Calendar"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="calPanel">
        <apex:form id="theForm" style="background: #f4f7f8;border-radius: 8px; width:50%; padding: 20px; margin:auto;">
            <apex:actionFunction name="setEvnt" action="{!setEvent}" reRender="pg" >
                <apex:param value="" name="item" assignTo="{!eventIdTemp}"/>
                <apex:param value="" name="test" assignTo="{!st}"/>
             <!--   <apex:param value="" name="test1" assignTo="{!ed}"/> -->
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: any javascript error?

Comment: No errros .. only warnings...I am getting Attempt to de-reference a null object error in .. List <String> dateParts = stringParts.split('-');

Comment: I have updated my code above...getting error in List <String>  stringParts = ed.split('T'); line...

Comment: it is because you haven't assigned any value to ed variable and it is null

Comment: Then how to assign value to ed?????

Comment: If you check this link..https://salesforceprojects.quora.com/Implement-full-calendar-drag-and-drop-in-Visualforce-page...how st & ed values are assigned.. can u check and let me know..

Comment: In the included code, the parameter "Ed" is commented out. You must uncomment it and call `setEvnt` with three parameters, not two.